# Multiple instance of single service

Tags: android, service, android-service

Suppose I have started a service from an activity and its running in the back ground and if I start the service again then will the service restart or will it have multiple instances?

Comment: none of them, the `Service` is a singleton and `onStartCommand` will be called again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [the docs](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/reference/android/app/Service.html#ServiceLifecycle) on service's lifecycle:

> There are two reasons that a service can be run by the system. If someone calls Context.startService() then the system will retrieve the service (creating it and calling its onCreate() method if needed) and then call its onStartCommand(Intent, int, int) method with the arguments supplied by the client. The service will at this point continue running until Context.stopService() or stopSelf() is called.
>
> Note that multiple calls to Context.startService() do not nest (though they do result in multiple corresponding calls to onStartCommand()), so no matter how many times it is started a service will be stopped once Context.stopService() or stopSelf() is called; however, services can use their stopSelf(int) method to ensure the service is not stopped until started intents have been processed.

Basically, it is created once (calling `onCreate`), and for each subsequent call to `startService`, the method `onStartCommand` is called again.

The server will determine whether or not to call `onCreate` itself, depending on if it was already running.

> if I start the service again then will the service restart

It will not recreate or reinitialize itself, but the code in `onStartCommand` is run again, so be sure to keep in mind that you don't do anything there that must not happen more than once. Do that in the `onCreate`.